# Trying to display all data from database table into Jtable using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, jtable

I'm trying to display all the data from different database table into a JTable using reflection but when i run the code I gen this kind of error:[image]. The methods responsible for that are createViewAllQuery, ViewAll and createObjects from AbstractDAO class.

Any idea what the problem is? Thanks!

```
package project3;

import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

public class AbstractDAO<T>{
        protected static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AbstractDAO.class.getName());

        private final Class<T> type;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public AbstractDAO() {
            this.type = (Class<T>)((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        }

        private String createFindQuery(String field) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("SELECT ");
            sb.append(" * ");
            sb.append(" FROM ");
            sb.append(type.getSimpleName());
            sb.append(" WHERE " + field + "=?");
            return sb.toString();
        }

        private String createAddQuery(T object) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("INSERT INTO ");
            sb.append(type.getSimpleName());
            sb.append(" VALUES (");
            for(Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if(field.get(object) instanceof Integer) {
                    sb.append(field.get(object));
                    sb.append(",");
                }
                else {
                    sb.append("'");
                    sb.append(field.get(object));
                    sb.append("',");
                }
            }
            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
            sb.append(");");
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
            return sb.toString();
        }

        private String createViewAllQuery() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("SELECT * FROM ");
            sb.append(type.getSimpleName());
            sb.append(";");
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public List<T> ViewAll() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
            Connection connection = null;
            PreparedStatement  statement = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;
            String query = createViewAllQuery();
            try {
                connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
                statement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
                return createObjects(resultSet);
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, type.getName() + "DAO:findByFirstName " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                ConnectionFactory.close(resultSet);
                ConnectionFactory.close(statement);
                ConnectionFactory.close(connection);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public JTable createTable(List<T> objects) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
            ArrayList<String> columnNamesArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            for(Field field : objects.get(0).getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                columnNamesArrayList.add(field.getName());
            }
            String[] columnNames = new String[columnNamesArrayList.size()];
            columnNames = columnNamesArrayList.toArray(columnNames);
            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
            Iterator<T> i = objects.iterator();
            while(i.hasNext()) {
                T object = i.next();
                ArrayList<Object> columnDataAsArrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();
                for(Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    columnDataAsArrayList.add(field.get(object));
                }
                Object[] columnDataAsArray = new Object[columnDataAsArrayList.size()];
                columnDataAsArray = columnDataAsArrayList.toArray(columnDataAsArray);
                tableModel.addRow(columnDataAsArray);
            }
            JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
            return table;
        }

        public void add(T object) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
            Connection connection = null;
            PreparedStatement  statement = null;
            String query = createAddQuery(object);
            try {
                connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
                statement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);
                statement.executeUpdate();
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, type.getName() + "DAO:findByFirstName " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                ConnectionFactory.close(statement);
                ConnectionFactory.close(connection);
            }
        }

        public List<T> findByFirstName(String firstName) {
            Connection connection = null;
            PreparedStatement  statement = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;
            String query = createFindQuery("first_name");
            try {
                connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
                statement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);
                statement.setString(1, firstName);
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

                return createObjects(resultSet);
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, type.getName() + "DAO:findByFirstName " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                ConnectionFactory.close(resultSet);
                ConnectionFactory.close(statement);
                ConnectionFactory.close(connection);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public T findById(int id) {
            Connection connection = null;
            PreparedStatement  statement = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;
            String query = createFindQuery("id");
            try {
                connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
                statement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);
                statement.setInt(1, id);
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

                return createObjects(resultSet).get(0);
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, type.getName() + "DAO:findById " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                ConnectionFactory.close(resultSet);
                ConnectionFactory.close(statement);
                ConnectionFactory.close(connection);
            }
            return null;
        }

        private List<T> createObjects(ResultSet resultSet){
            List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

            try {
                try {
                    while(resultSet.next()) {
                        T instance = type.newInstance();
                        for(Field field: type.getDeclaredFields()) {
                            Object value =  resultSet.getObject(field.getName());
                            PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = new  PropertyDescriptor(field.getName(), type);
                            Method method = propertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod();
                            method.invoke(instance, value);
                        }
                        list.add(instance);
                    }
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | SQLException | IntrospectionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }catch(InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return list;
        }

}

package project3;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument.Iterator;

public class ProductsDAO extends AbstractDAO<Products>{
    public ProductsDAO() {}; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProductsDAO p1 = new ProductsDAO();
        //Products product1 = new Products(3, "cascaval", 5, " tip de branza facuta din lapte de vaca sau oaie", 4680);
        try {
            JTable table = new JTable();
            table = p1.createTable(p1.ViewAll());

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setSize(300, 150);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            /*List<Products> list = new ArrayList<Products>();
            list = p1.ViewAll();
            java.util.Iterator<Products> i = list.iterator();
            while(i.hasNext()) {
                Products x = i.next();
                System.out.println(x.getDescription());
            }*/


        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is one of the classes:

```
package project3;

public class Products {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int price;
    private String description;
    private int stoc;

    public Products(int id, String name, int price, String description, int stoc) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
        this.stoc = stoc;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getStoc() {
        return stoc;
    }

    public void setStoc(int stoc) {
        this.stoc = stoc;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the constructor of AbstractDAO verífy de number of elements in the array obtained from the call getActualTypeArguments(). 
Probably it's returning an array with no elements, and you are trying to get the first element (index 0).

Comment: Yeah, i kinda fixed that but the NoSuchMethodException is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `Products` hasn't got a default-constructor (so no method `<init>`), but you're trying to use that in

```
T instance = type.newInstance();
```

Since the Method isn't there the `NoSuchMethodException` is thrown.

You either have to add a default-constructor like

```
public Products() {
    ...
}
```

or call the constructor with arguments (probably harder to do ;)